# Does it matter if height constraint is not set?

Tags: swift, autolayout, tableview, constraints

I'm setting up constraints programmatically in Swift 3 and have a question about constraints. If I don't set a height constraint but set a `topAnchor` and `bottomAnchor`, does that do the same thing?

```
self.squadTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.squadTableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:     self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
self.squadTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:   self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
self.squadTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
self.squadTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Compared to taking out the `bottomAnchor` constraint and then doing

```
self.squadTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a top and bottom is sufficient if they are anchored to things that have sufficient constraints.  You just need constraints that determine position and size, but it can be any combination that does that.

Comment: I don't get it. Say you have 4 labels, from top to bottom, how would you position these using autolayout. what I mean is you have 3 kinds of constraints: first label and top of view, between 2 labels, last label and bottom of view. How would I specify these constraints so that it not stretch out the spaces in between too much nor it would stretch out the height of the labels themselves? Would I give percentage-base spaces/distances/heights or just fixed amounts (which is different for iPhone5,6,plus, iPad mini, iPad Air, iPad Pro). I just want a rough idea, don't need the code...

Comment: @Honey Constraints don't need to be equal to a number, they can be set to be <=.  You probably need to overspecify the constraint and use priorities so it knows which one takes precedence.  You can also make a constraint == to another but with a multiplier -- that's the normal way to do a percentage-based one.  If you want more details, best thing to do is to write a question

Comment: You can also provide different constraints for different size classes.